# LZW compression & dictionary implementation using hashing

Tags: hash, compression, lzw

I have a long text which has to be compressed using LZW compression algorithm. I have to assign 16 bit code for sequence of ASCII characters. for eg 'aa' will have 16-bit code '0000000010000000' (just available after 'DEL' ie 0000000001111111). Now before starting compression I have to initialize the dictionary which is 
'NUL':0000000000000000
'SOH': 0000000000000001,
.
.
.
. 
'DEL':0000000001111111.

I have to use hashing to implement this dictionary. Now I need help in understanding this statement that how hashing is used to implement the dictionary. Also please suggest me hash function that will do the job. Side note- I have to use quadratic probing to handle collisions.

Answer (score 0):

LZW doesn't require collision handling because its dictionary hash requires just 32 MB memory and it is not a problem in 2019. See [sparse array dictionary](https://github.com/andrew-aladev/lzws/blob/master/src/compressor/dictionary/sparse-array/main.c) in [lzws](https://github.com/andrew-aladev/lzws).